# Bash Script Won't Run - Word unexpected and unexpected token

Tags: windows, bash, shell, scripting, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I have 1 bash scripts,

findFungible.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $*;
    for word in $(cat $file);
        if [ $word == Fungible ];
            echo Fungible found
        fi
    done
done
```

Which should be checking files if they contain the word fungible.
It's pretty much verbatim out of my lecture example.

So if I run it with bash `findFungible.sh`
I get:

```
findFungible.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token "$\r''
'indFungible.sh: line 2: 'for file in $*;
```

So I think it has something to do with windows putting in extra line \r characters or something. As there is a \r after $.

Then if I run it with `sh findFungible.sh`
I get:

```
findFungible.sh: 2: findFungible.sh Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: `help for` and try https://shellcheck.net also that error is windows line endings which is a carriage return.

Comment: See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) Also, for such a short script this is extremely dense in bad scripting practices (mostly having to do with unquoted variable references). And it's missing `do` and `then` keywords. I don't think I trust that lecture you're following...

Comment: Trying to use `for var in $(cat file)` to read the lines of a file is wrong too; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: @Argon : If you look at your script with `xxd findFungible.sh`, you will see that there are carriage returns in your script.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned in a reply, you have syntax errors in this, meaning, you are missing "do's" and "then's".

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $*; do
    for word in $(cat $file); do
        if [ $word == Fungible ]; then
            echo Fungible found
        fi
    done
done
```

And yes, like mentioned in the reply, bash is very sensitive to white spaces, new lines and quotes, I'm not getting into too much detail there.